# How to write interface for a go function with multi return values with JNA

Tags: java, go, jna, multiple-return-values

I'm trying to export some Go functions and call them in Java, with [JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna), but I don't know how to define the interface in Java for a Go function with multiple return values.

Say the Go function is:

```
//export generateKeys
func generateKeys() (privateKey, publicKey []byte) {
    return .....
}
```

The return values has two items, but in Java, there is only one return value allowed.

What can I do?

Comment: You'll first want to figure out how you could call that from C, then translate that to work with JNA. I have no idea how Go's compiler handles multiple return values, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cgo` creates a dedicated C struct for multiple return values, with the individual return values as struct elements.

In your example, `cgo` would generate

```
/* Return type for generateKeys */
struct generateKeys_return {
    GoSlice r0; /* privateKey */
    GoSlice r1; /* publicKey */
};
```

and the function would have a different signature, which you then use via JNA

```
extern struct generateKeys_return generateKeys();
```

In your JNA definition, you'd then resemble the structure using JNA concepts (**untested code**):

```
public interface Generator extends Library {

        public class GoSlice extends Structure {
            public Pointer data;
            public long len;
            public long cap;
            protected List getFieldOrder(){
                return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"data","len","cap"});
            }
        }

        public class GenerateKeysResult extends Structure {
            public GoSlice privateKey;
            public GoSlice publicKey;
            protected List getFieldOrder(){
                return Arrays.asList(new String[]{"privateKey","publicKey"});
            }
        }

        public GenerateKeysResult generateKeys();
}
```

Comment: Finally I make it work inspired of your answer, thanks. There is something notable, we can't return `[]type` in Go functions, instead, we should use `unsafe.Pointer`, otherwise cgo will report error like "It exports a go pointer"

Comment: The working demo is here: <https://github.com/golang-demos/call-go-function-from-java-demo/blob/stackoverflow/src/main/java/demo/Hello.java#L52-L61>. There probably be something wrong since I don't how to free the pointers where the document says it needs to